# write_csv Error in stream_delim_(df, path, ...) : invalid connection

Tags: r, readr

I have a doubt about why write_csv is not working in the following example, but write.csv is working properly. In general, I use the packages "dplyr" and "readr" as they are fast. However, I am not sure why this is happening.

```
write_csv(df1, path = "C:\\Users\\Sergio\\final\\file1.csv" ,col_names = TRUE)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in stream_delim_(df, path, ...) : invalid connection
```

However, if I write the following code, it works ok.

```
write.csv(df1, file = "file1.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8")
```

I am using R version 3.4.1 64-bit, and RStudio Version 1.0.143. My OS is Windows 10. I would appreciate your comments. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may have misspecified the file path. You should make sure both commands point to the same directory:

> ```
> write.csv(df1, file = "C:\\Users\\Sergio\\final\\file1.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8")
> ```

If that fails, you've misspecified the directory.